# How to create a Vecs of register by Chisel

Tags: chisel

I will use Chisel3 to construct a register set.
The Chisel code is:

```
 val register_set = Reg(Vec(7,UInt(32.W)))
```

But the synthesized Verilog code is:

```
 reg [31:0] register_set_0;
 reg [31:0] register_set_1;
 reg [31:0] register_set_2;
 reg [31:0] register_set_3;
 reg [31:0] register_set_4;
 reg [31:0] register_set_5;
 reg [31:0] register_set_6;
```

How should I change my Chisel code in order to synthesize the Verilog code like this:

```
reg [31:0]  register_set [0:6];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel currently cannot emit Verilog arrays. This is obviously a highly desirable feature and is on our TODO list but it is not yet implemented.